C++ Extension for PyTorch - Missing DLL
I'm writing a C++ extension for PyTorch on Windows in Visual Studio 2022. Everything compiles correctly, but both ways I've tried (via CMake and via a setup.py file) I get the same error when importing the module:

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing TorchExtensions: The specified module could not be found.

I've used the Developer Command Prompt to write dumpbin /dependents <my TorchExtensions file name> to check for the DLL dependencies and nothing stands out - everything should be handled either by torch or by pybind11.
My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_subdirectory("pybind11")
find_package(Torch CONFIG REQUIRED HINTS "$ENV{CONDA_PATH}\\Lib\\site-packages\\torch\\share\\cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(Python_EXECUTABLE "$ENV{CONDA_PATH}\\python.exe")
find_package(Python REQUIRED)

PYBIND11_ADD_MODULE(TorchExtensions "TorchExtensions.cpp" "TorchExtensions.h")

set(Python_LIBRARY "$ENV{CONDA_PATH}\\libs\\python311.lib")
set(Python_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{CONDA_PATH}\\include")

target_include_directories(TorchExtensions PUBLIC ${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(TorchExtensions PUBLIC ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} ${Python_LIBRARY})


Am I missing anything here? I'm very new to CMake and C++ so if I've missed something obvious I do apologise. I see nothing in the CMake file in e.g. this post which leads me to think that I've missed something.
